# Batch File - Know if disk is partitioned or not

Tags: windows, partitioning, batch, wmic

I am working on Winpe environment, how to get informations if the disk 0 is partitioned or not to launch specific commands on each case
i have tried this, but how to get this works properly in a batch file?

```
set part_inst=wmic partition list instance
```

if the disk is not initialized it will return :

```
No Available Instance.
```

else if partitions are found it will return :

```
Index
0
1
2
```

how to use this information in a batch file to launch the procedure like this

```
if %part_inst% == "No Available Instance." (
Rem execute sequence_1 of commands if disk is **_not partitioned_**
) else (
Rem execute sequence_2 of commands if disk is **_partitioned_**
)
```

Comment: Look like a solid plan, where exactly does it fail?
The only possible problem I see is that there are no quotes around %part_inst% on the IF line.

Comment: Yes i forget to remove the quotes, the syntax in command prompt would be :
     if part_inst="No Available Instance."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding Oliver Salzburg's answer, here's an example snippet which works out of the box in Windows PE, where only the `find` command is available by default. I also changed the actual variable check in order to make it as language-independent as possible:

```
@echo off

set part_inst=

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
`wmic partition list instance /format:list ^| find "="`
) do set part_inst=%%A

if not defined part_inst (
REM execute sequence_1 of commands if disk is **_not partitioned_**
) else (
REM execute sequence_2 of commands if disk is **_partitioned_**
)
```

Comment: when the part_inst is not defined it contains `"` why?

Comment: @madoui20032003 When a variable is not defined it should be empty, but as long the correct sequence gets executed it's probably not an issue.

Comment: yes the script works fine it was a hidden character in my batch file, sorry.

Comment: @madoui20032003 Good to see you sorted it out.

Comment: `PS`: The script works fine when there is only one hard disk, and no USB storage must be plugged in.
Are there any suggestions to test on disk 0 only?

Comment: @madoui20032003 You could replace the `wmic` part with the following code: `wmic partition where diskindex=0 get index /format:list`

Answer (score 1):

To store the result of an executed command into a variable, you can't simply assign it using `set`.

A popular approach is to use `for` as outlined in the StackOverflow question [Windows batch files: How to set a variable with the result of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889518/windows-batch-files-how-to-set-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command).

You might need to combine that with the suggestion from [How can I remove empty lines from wmic output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685816/how-can-i-remove-empty-lines-from-wmic-output):

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (
  'wmic partition list instance' ^| findstr /r /v "^$"'
) do @set part_inst=%%a
```

Comment: When executed on command prompt, in both cases "new disk" "Partitioned disk", the variable %part_inst% is null?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. The output of `wmic` ends with a new line. So the the last iteration over the output clears the variable. You might need to `CALL` a subroutine in your batch file to properly parse the output.

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for; you can say that the question is answered.

Comment: `PS:` in windows PE the file `findstr.exe` is not found, so it is advised to add it before doing the manipulation.